# Railsadmin and mutlilanguage options

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-admin

I am using railsadmin for content management. I want to add 2 new laguages to my site. What are my options ? Someone ideas ?  I can't find any info about this subject on github/rails_admin

Grtz..emco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not add to the content page like - rails g migration add_lang_to_pages lang_1_title:string lang_1_conent:text lang_2_title:string lang_2_content:text

Then do - rake db:migrate and the start up rails admin and the new language fields should be there.